# Console linking for Overwatch

Tags: ps4, overwatch, nintendo-switch

I recently bought Overwatch for Nintendo Switch but I have a ton of progress on PS4 too.

I have linked my respective consoles on battlenet but it doesnt seem to have any effect.

Is there a way of getting that progress on to Switch too so im not starting over? Is this even doable?

I have checked the support on battlenet.

I have logged in to my overwatch account and its showing my new Nintendo Switch progress, no sign of my PS4 progress.

Comment: ...have you logged in on switch?

Comment: @Corsaka Logged into what?

Comment: Your overwatch account @UIO

Comment: @Corsaka yes, but im not seeing my ps4 progress on it (under a different name)

Comment: Overwatch doesn't have cross-platform accounts...

Comment: Thats a bit annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwatch does not has any kind of cross platform progress storage or transfer. All of the progress that you obtain is specific for your platform and account.

The only thing that is shared is the number of Overwatch League points obtained via watching streams. Let's say that you get 500 OWL points by watching the league, you will get 500 points on each platform that you have linked. This should not be confused with progress sync, because any skins purchased on the account will stay on that account and will not be synced with the other platforms. The number of points is tracked per platform.